# how to use hash inside instance_eval ruby?

Tags: ruby

Here is class foo

```
class Foo
  def initialize(&block)
    instance_eval(&block) if block
  end

  def bar(hash)
    @bar = hash
  end
end
```

why is this syntax error

```
foo = Foo.new do
  bar {:param1=>'value1', :param2=>"value2"}
end
```

the syntax error this gives me is
`SyntaxError: unexpected ',', expecting '}'
  bar {:param1=>'value1',:param2=>'value2'}` whats the proper way to use hash inside instance_eval like the example above. What i really need is to pass in hash to a method inside instance_eval

Comment: Add parentheses and you're good to go: `bar({:param1=>'value1', :param2=>"value2"})`. As it  is, `{:param1=>'value1', :param2=>"value2"}` is treated as block rather than an argument.

Comment: thanks you solved my problem

Comment: You can alternatively write `bar :param1=>'value1', :param2=>"value2"`or `bar param1: 'value1', param2: "value2"` (or the same with parentheses).

Comment: thanks a lot now it will feel less ugly without those parenthesis.