# Instance variable inside singleton class

Tags: ruby, singleton

I have the following piece of code:

```
class Fish
# @message = "I can swim"

 class << self
  @message = "I can jump!"
  define_method(:action) { @message }
 end
end


Fish.action  => nil
```

As soon as I uncomment the above `@message` variable, `Fish.action` returns `I can swim`. Why in both cases it is ignoring the `I can jump` message. Why is that? Why is Fish class being binded to the `@message` defined at the start but not inside the `singleton` class?

Comment: This is oh-so-close to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40211113/how-to-use-hash-inside-instance-eval-ruby) just asked a few minutes ago. If you move the definition of the class method `action` outside the singleton class and define it (equivalently) `def self.action; @message; end`, the answers to the earlier question would apply to your question as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because `class << self` opens the class' singleton class context:

```
class Foo
  p self # Foo
  class << self
    p self # #<Class:Foo>
    define_method(:bar) { p self } # Foo
  end
end
Foo.bar
```

You can verify that by:

```
Fish.singleton_class.instance_variable_get(:@action) # => "I can jump!"
```

Comment: Can we say "`class << self` changes `self` to `Foo`'s singleton class"? It seems more precise to me. I know "open a class" is often used, but nowhere (as far as I know) does Ruby provide a definition for "opening" a class.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, this implies that only `self` changes, but the current class also changes (think of it like `instance_eval` vs `class_eval`).

Comment: I think we're saying the same thing, that `self` is changed to  `Foo.singleton_class` between `class << self` and its `end`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, I'm saying something more. *"`class << self` changes `self` to `Foo`'s singleton class"* basically means `class << self; _something_; end` and `singleton_class.instance_eval { _something_ }` are equivalent (they are not). *"Opens `Foo`'s ' singleton class context"* is the equivalent of  `singleton_class.class_eval { _something_ }`

Comment: @ndn why is `self` inside the `define_method` block the `Foo` class itself but not the singleton class?

Comment: @mhaseeb, for the same reason given `class Bar; p self; def baz; p self; end; end`, the `self` outside the method will be `Bar`, but the `self` inside the method will be whatever instance you call it on. Methods are defined in classes, but act on the instances of said classes.